# How can I suggest to break one tag into more?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

For example, on stackoverflow, we have a tag called [optimization](/questions/tagged/optimization). Most of the time, it is in the performance optimization context. However, it may also refer to `numerical optimization`, which is totally different.

So how can we make suggestions to break the tag [optimization](/questions/tagged/optimization) to

```
- performance-optimization
- numerical-optimization?
```

**Edit**: I noticed currently we also have [mathematical-optimization](/questions/tagged/mathematical-optimization) which are possible synonyms of `numerical-optimization`.

Comment: Oh and whatever you choose to do, please do not go on a mass re-tagging spree without prior approval from meta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/create-tags). As long as you have 1500 reputations, you can create your own tags.